# accept regular expression from user and display entries from database in PHP

Tags: php, regex

This is in PHP. I am accepting a string in which user enters regular expression and I need to pass this in Select query to extract and display file names which matches the expression.

For eg.if user enters `*.pdf`, it should return all pdf files; if user enters ^temp, then all files starting with temp should be displayed and so on.

My string is reaching out properly, but i am not able to form the query.
I am storing a string in $parameter and the query is like this:

```
$result=mysql_query("select filename from fileinfo where filetype REGEXP '$parameter'");
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems I see

1. You're using glob syntax (e.g. *.pdf) instead of an correct regexp syntax.  `'.*\\.pdf'` would be a valid regexp equivalent of `'*.pdf'` (which should always fail, since it's invalid)
2. It looks like you are incorrectly testing FILETYPE instead of FILENAME?  Try this instead:

   `$result=mysql_query("select filename from fileinfo where filename REGEXP '{$parameter}'");`

Finally, try echoing your SQL to ensure you're running the query you think you are.  You may have some escaping issues.

Comment: Thanks Steven, but even though we enter just regular expression like ^temp, then also its not displaying. I can leave global syntax for the time being.

Comment: Added another idea... should you be testing on `filename` instead of `filetype`?

Comment: I am testing on filename only, I am leaving that *.pdf thing for the time being because I already provided another option for the user to just enter file extension and list the file.

Comment: Ok, well note in your query that your REGEXP is on file TYPE, not NAME.  I corrected it in my answer above.  Try that out and see if it fixes it for you.

Comment: But, that will be just for filetype then, I don't want that. I want this on file name, you can query my files anyhow using any regular expression. I want that...

Comment: You have it backwards.  Look at your query in your question.  You're NOT testing FILENAME... you ARE testing FILETYPE.  Just do me the favor of trying my answer and I think you'll see it fixes your problem.  Cheers

Comment: Hey Steven, I am really sorry. How can I make such a silly mistake. Thank you so much from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: Consider use `mysql_escape_string()` In your string parameter or any other sanitize method - that's because if the user can input/chose the regex type, your SQL may be vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: No worries, Dave.  That's what a second pair of eyes is for!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result=mysql_query("select filename from fileinfo where filetype REGEXP '".$parameter."');
```

Comment: Wrap the regexp in quotes (`' '`). Also note that MySQL doesn't use PCRE regular expressions (like PHP does with the `preg_*` functions) but [extended POSIX syntax ('ERE')](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions).

Comment: I tried that also, but was unsuccessful. Sorry, but I didn't get your POSIX and preg function point, can you please tell me what changes I should make in my query

Comment: Changed the query a little to use quotes a little different from your query. Did you check what the query looks like, by assigning it to a variable for a moment and echo it?

Comment: Hey RST, Sorry. Its done now. I have to change it from filetype to filename. My mistake. Really apologize. Thanks for all your help and support.